# Having return in every if & else if & else statements vs one return at the end of code

Tags: java, if-statement, return

Hello I have a quick question about multiple return statements vs single return statement at the end of the code.

From the first code, used return statement for every if, else if, and else statments and it gave me an error. And I thought I covered every possible cases but it game me an error bellow.

ERROR :
missing return statement line:16

What causes this error? Also, are there any way that I can improve my second code?

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
    if (!isBirthday)
        if (speed <= 60)
            return 0;
        else if (speed <= 80)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 2;
    if (isBirthday)
        if (speed <= 65)
            return 0;
        else if (speed <= 85)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 2;
}
```

From this second code, I was able to get rid of the error.

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
    int flag = 0;
    if (!isBirthday)
        if (speed <= 60)
            flag = 0;
        else if (speed <= 80)
            flag = 1;
        else 
            flag = 2;
    if (isBirthday)
        if (speed <= 65)
            flag = 0;
        else if (speed <= 85)
            flag = 1;
        else 
            flag = 2;
        return flag;
}
```

Comment: Replace `if(isBirthday)` with `else`

Comment: Nested if statements without braces are asking for trouble. Do yourself and everyone else reading or maintaining your code a favour and use `{}`.

Comment: replacing if(isBirthday) with else solved the problem! Thanks.
And I had my {} for my if statements but missed it when I copy my code to this post. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code you test `isBirthday` and `!isBirthday`. Java isn’t smart enough to see that this list is exhaustive. And you wouldn’t normally write it like that, anyway: you’d write `else` instead.

```
public int caughtSpeeding(int speed, boolean isBirthday) {
    if (!isBirthday) {
        if (speed <= 60)
            return 0;
        else if (speed <= 80)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 2;
    } else {
        if (speed <= 65)
            return 0;
        else if (speed <= 85)
            return 1;
        else 
            return 2;
    }
}
```

> Also, are there any way that I can improve my second code?

Yes: by using the first code. The second code uses a completely redundant variable. Use the first code.

In fact, because the second code uses a variable, Java won’t warn you if you forget a case — it will silently return `0`, because that’s how `flag` was initialised. That would be a bug. When possible, write code that can’t lead to bugs but triggers compile errors instead — that’s what code 1 does, hence the error message (which was a false positive in this case, but which is in general correct).

Comment: To prevent silently returning 0, should I change int flag = 0; to int flag = -1;   ??

Comment: @user13316090 No, that changes very little. Now your function will silently return -1. Really, you can completely prevent this class of errors by going with solution 1 instead of solution 2.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's sort-of obvious to us that one if "if birthday" and "if not birthday" is going to be executed, but the Java compiler doesn't see it that way.

To it, if the first 'if' does not get executed, and the second 'if' also does not get executed, then you come to the end of the method without executing a 'return'.